# Chinese software installed.. how to remove

Tags: laptop

I downloaded a software from a un-trusted site and few Chinese software installed in my computer... 
Below is screenshot..
Its not "TENCENT"

[image]

Comment: It looks like, based off what the chinese file types are, that it's compression software. If you run appwiz.cpl and see installed applications, are there any compression applications there that could be removed?

Comment: There is no file.. i removed all files that was extra but still same

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use the following .reg file.  You should make a export the following in order to be able to go back to what you have currently.

- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew\Config
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lnk\ShellNew
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lnk\ShellNew\Config
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.bmp\ShellNew
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.contact\ShellNew
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.jnt\jntfile\ShellNew
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\ShellNew
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.txt\ShellNew
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.zip\CompressedFolder\ShellNew

> 1. Download the following [.reg](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/39963d1443461139-new-context-menu-restore-default-items-windows-10-a-restore_default_new_context_menu_items.reg)
>      file
> 2. Double click/tap on the downloaded .reg file to merge it.
> 3. If prompted, click on Run, Yes (UAC), Yes, and OK to approve the merge.
> 4. You can now delete the downloaded .reg file if you like.
> 5. Done

Source: [How to Restore Default New Context Menu Items in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24412-new-context-menu-restore-default-items-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: You could also just use a restore point from before you installed the software you installed.  If you have any programs, that added their own new context menu items options, those will have to be reinstalled.  *This answer has a specific focus on how to remove the non-english new context menu options.*

Comment: I will have to see, if I can find a way to provide the registry file within the body of my answer, I hate having to link to an external file.